# How to omit preceding value when calling method with default arguments?

Tags: scala, parameters, default

I have a function as below

```
def add(a: Int = 10, b: Int = 15): Int = {
  var sum: Int = 0
  sum = a + b
  return sum
}
```

When I call using `add(5, 5)`, output is 10.
When I call using `add()`, output is 25, as defaults are used.
When I call using `add(8)` i.e. a single value, a is assigned 8, so total is 23.

Now, I want to assign default value to a and pass b only.

I tried `add(, 6)`, but it gives an error.

Comment: Use named parameters: `add(b = 6)`. Note that your definition is missing an `=` sign.

Comment: Don't use `var`. Why are you using it? Why not just write `def add(a: Int=10, b: Int=15) = a+b`?  Every time you think you want to use `var`, ask yourself this: "_why_ do I think I want ti use it?"

Comment: Although using `named parameters` works, I would question why you're using default parameters in this case. I find `add(10, 6)` more readable than `add(b=6)`. I admit that I'm biased in favor of explicit over implicit, i.e. default value in this case, in general.

Answer (score 2):

Since Scala supports named parameters, you can do:

```
add(b = 6) // 16
```